# Xcode - Cocos2D Particle system example - pointer usage

Tags: xcode, cocos2d-iphone

There's an iphone app Fluid Toy which uses a particle system. The author released the source of the particles generator [simpleparticles source](http://www.nulldesign.de/wp-content/uploads/2011/03/Cocos2DSimpleParticleSystem.zip) but I can't use it because I don't know how to access his particles which are created as:-

```
particles = (SimpleParticle *) malloc(sizeof(SimpleParticle) * maxParticles);
```

The particle system is initialised

```
  particles = [SimpleParticleSystem node];
  [particles initialize: 1000 width: 20 height: 20];
```

But the code snippet shows accessing the individual particles

```
while(count < particles.particleCount)
{
   p = &particleAr[count];
   p->dir.x += CCRANDOM_MINUS1_1();
   p->dir.y += CCRANDOM_MINUS1_1();
```

and I'm stuck understanding how **particleAr** is defined. It's some sort of pointer to the memory containing the particles.

Any suggestions on how to get this working would be welcome.
It's a Cocos2d / 3D demo I'm working on and the built-in particles don't do exactly what I want.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 'particleAr' just looks like an array of particles no?  Isn't 'p' (the particle) the variable you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

sounds like an exciting project. :-)

I've used (played with) [Particle Designer](http://particledesigner.71squared.com/) for some basic 2D particles like fire, smoke etc. You'll probably already have looked at this as Cocos2D supports it natively, I just thought i'd throw out a comment.